# NullRefrenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code below is placed in page_Load. How I should handle this to bypass UrlReferrer when you enter page directly first time and there is no referrer? 
What I am missing here?

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri != null)
    {
        urlReferer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        urlReferer = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this way much cleaner than checking nulls

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
        {
            urlReferer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            urlReferer = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just check `UrlReferrer`for null:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null 
    && HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri != null)
{
     urlReferer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
}     
else     
{         
    urlReferer = "";     
}
```

Comment: When try to check for if(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri != Null) then throws the NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object so I can't use this syntax but checking for if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null ) is working in my code also placing it in (!IsPostBack) makes it even better.

Answer (score 3):

Who says the client passed by the referrer in the HTTP request?

Check if `UrlReferrer` is `null` first

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    {
        urlReferer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        urlReferer = "";
    }
```

Comment: This will throw NullReferenceException if `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri == null`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to check if `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null`.

Answer (score 0):

If UrlReferrer is null, then the test to AbsolutUri will fail.

Try initially testing UrlReferrer for null, this will probably correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use your debugger.  If you're running this out of visual studio, than you might be brought to a debugger window when the exception is thrown.  There are multiple tabs at the bottom of the debugger including "Locals" and "Watch"  you can use those to see what variables are being stored.

If the above code is indeed what's causing the problem than

`HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri`
or
`HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer`
or
`HttpContext.Current.Request`
or
`HttpContext.Current`
or
`HttpContext`

is set to null